# DOM className property not working in setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I am trying to create a react component that can render either a "peg":

[image: Imgur]

Or a "nopeg" (which is just a white space with no peg). This is done just by changing the class of the Peg component. I also have another purpose. If the peg is clicked and its class is "nopeg", then I want to change the Peg to the "peg" class imediatly, then wait 1 second, and then change it back to "nopeg". This is done using React.js:

```
class Peg extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleDrop = this.handleDrop.bind(this);
  }

  handleDrop(event) {

    if (event.target.className == 'nopeg') {
      event.target.className = 'peg'

      setTimeout((e) => {
        e.target.className = 'nopeg'
      }, 1000, event)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const classdef = this.props.class;
    const iddef = this.props.id;
    return <div id={iddef} class={classdef} onClick={this.handleDrop}></div>
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `setTimeout` function handles the wait by inputing the event object, waiting for 1 second, and then changing the classname. This doesn't work for some reason and I'm only able to change the peg to "nopeg".

Comment: Should `event.target.className = 'nopeg'. Not e`

Comment: No I'm passing the event object into the setTimout function as the third parameter. See setTimeout Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout @ThanhNgo

Comment: @Herohtar I'm using codepen.io and there's no error when it renders. The `e.target.className = 'nopeg'` just doesn't excecute

Comment: Could you share codepen.io

Comment: It's a bit more complicated. Type `3` into top and `2` into side and it will render the pegs. Click on a space in between the pegs to start the handleClick function: https://codepen.io/lectrician1/pen/BbPadN

Comment: I'm not sure why you aren't getting the synthetic event error message in your codepen, but that is the problem. You should pass `event.target` instead.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

Comment: Sorry there. I meant to say that I was only able to change it on the 11th line for the code I posted: `event.target.className = 'peg'` changes it successfully. That code is outside of the setTimeout function though. @JaromandaX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React uses synthetic events. As described in the [event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) section of the documentation, those events are reused, so you can not access them later from asynchronous code (such as a `setTimeout` callback). If you want to pass it to `setTimeout` you will either need to call `event.persist()` first, or pass the value of `event.target` instead:

**With `event.persist()`:**

```
if (event.target.className == 'nopeg') {
  event.target.className = 'peg'
  event.persist()

  setTimeout((e) => {
    e.target.className = 'nopeg'
  }, 1000, event)
}
```

**Passing `event.target`:**

```
if (event.target.className == 'nopeg') {
  event.target.className = 'peg'

  setTimeout((t) => {
    t.className = 'nopeg'
  }, 1000, event.target)
}
```